# Create an app shortcut to open it with restricted permissions

Tags: permissions, home-screen-shortcuts, geolocation, location-services

Is there a way to create a specific shortcut for an app that would open it with limited permissions that I specify?

For example, I want to create a shortcut to open Snapchat (an app which uses location a lot) with location permission denied, but if I opened it with the normal shortcut, it would open it with the normal permissions I've given it in settings. Currently, the only options I see are manually enabling and disabling location or battery saver, or turning off location access for Snapchat through settings. But both of these take more time than I'd like!

I tried looking through the settings menus and play store but couldn't find anything to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Not natively. And not with any app on Playstore that I know of. There is, however, an app provided by "Backes SRT". That would of course require you trust them enough, as the app enabling that feature requires a lot of permissions itself (to handle the permissions for "caged apps"). IIRC, [SRT AppGuard](http://www.srt-appguard.com/) was the one. You could then create a shortcut to the caged app, and another one to the original app. In case I picked the wrong app, [here are the others](https://www.backes-srt.com/en/solutions-2/) (UserControl sounds like it).

Comment: Let us know your success then :)